# Android image not updated on orientation change, titanium mobile sdk v2.1.1

Tags: android, sdk, orientation, titanium, resolution

I'm changing navigation bar background image on orientation change. but its not working in sdk  version 2.1.1.

having different resolution images in res-land-ldpi and res-port-ldpi for different orientations. but the path is not properly updated on orientation change, image not updated properly even orientation change event listener working properly.

Answer (score 0):

try doing the same in the override method onConfigurationChanged() make entry in the android manifest on onConfigChange for orienatation

Comment: its seems that the path is getting updated but not changing the image.  I am using ImageView i tried both setImage and setBackgroundImage..

Comment: have you overrided this method you can use setImageResource of that changed images ofcourse you have to store them by seperate name like Image1 when it is in potrait mode onConfig change like orientation change change the setImageResource to image2 it's really simple

Comment: I did the same successfully, but I tried to use default folders res-land-ldpi and res-port-ldpi for different orientations.

Comment: It is slightly difficult to work with so I generally stick to different layout files with different names in the layout folder